# JQuery Autocomplete does not allow selection with the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I can't get the item selected from the result set of jQuery UI Autocomplete to appear in the textbox after clicking on it, however i can navigate through them with keyboard and select with enter key. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#t1').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                // prepare url : for example '/api/artistapi?query=sonu
                var autocompleteUrl = '/api/KeywordAutoComplete/' + request.term;
                $.ajax({
                    url: autocompleteUrl,
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (json) {
                        // call autocomplete callback method with results
                        response($.map(json, function (data, id) {
                            return {
                                label: data.KeyText

                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('some error occured', textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                $('#autocomplete-textbox').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I went trough some similar questions on Stackoverflow but none of them solved my issue. Some have suggested that the problem happens if in your header section you load more than one JQuery-UI  Libraries. Here is my my header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Eliminating any of these lines from my header did not help. Thank you all

Comment: Can we have a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: Is this possible in the demos in official site? If not, this should be a feature request in their forum...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1o4kb01v/1/... I just mocked the AJAX response. Make sure the `id` is correct in your markup

Comment: Can we assume the missing close `});` of the document ready function is just a paste typo?  It appears something ELSE on your page is at fault here, perhaps trapping the click event?  Perhaps show some markup or other code?